# Populate textboxes via a series of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to populate a series of textboxes from a number of checkboxes. There are 8 text boxes and it seems that code will only populate one of these fields.

here is the checkboxes:

```
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox0" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox1" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox2" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox3" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox4" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox5" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox6" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input name="naicscode" id="naicsCodeCheckbox7" class="naicsCodeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="secondaryNaicsButton" name="save_value" value="Save" />
```

heres the textboxes:

```
<input name="secondaryNaicsCodeField" id="secondaryNaicsCode0" class="fpp_textfield NAICS-code-field" value=""  type="text" />
<input name="secondaryNaicsCodeField" id="secondaryNaicsCode1" class="fpp_textfield NAICS-code-field" value=""  type="text" />
<input name="secondaryNaicsCodeField" id="secondaryNaicsCode2" class="fpp_textfield NAICS-code-field" value=""  type="text" />
<input name="secondaryNaicsCodeField" id="secondaryNaicsCode3" class="fpp_textfield NAICS-code-field" value=""  type="text" />
<input name="secondaryNaicsCodeField" id="secondaryNaicsCode4" class="fpp_textfield NAICS-code-field" value=""  type="text" />
<input name="secondaryNaicsCodeField" id="secondaryNaicsCode5" class="fpp_textfield NAICS-code-field" value=""  type="text" />
```

here is my jQuery:

```
 // gets values of check box in Secondary NAICS list
 $('#secondaryNaicsButton').click(function() {
   $('.naicsCodeCheckbox:checked').each(function(i){
   var val = [] 
   val[i] = $(this).val();
   for (var i =0; i < val.length; i++) {
     $('#secondaryNaicsCode'+i).val(val[i]);
   }
 });
```

the result i'm getting is that it will give the value of one of the check boxes and put it in text box 3 or 4.

this is what console log is giving me :

```
111140                        fol_reg_form.js:215
undefined                     fol_reg_form.js:215
111150                        fol_reg_form.js:215
2
undefined                     fol_reg_form.js:215
111219                        fol_reg_form.js:215
3
undefined                     fol_reg_form.js:215
111331                        fol_reg_form.js:215
4
undefined                     fol_reg_form.js:215
111334
```

Comment: as @Sergio mentioned you have the wrong selector and it should be '.naicsCodeCheckbox' instead of '.naicscode', the other thing is that you select only the checkbox that have been check and 'i' is the index of that array and not of the complete (checked and unchecked), so you need to select all the checkbox and then check if it's been checked

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#secondaryNaicsButton').click(function () {
    $('.naicsCodeCheckbox').each(function (i) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#secondaryNaicsCode' + i).val(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w4tB6/2/)

Note: in your code you have no class with name `.naicscode`, so I used class `naicsCodeCheckbox` instead. If you want to go by name you can use the same code but with `$('input[name="naicscode"]').each( //etc ...` instead.

Comment: I tried the suggested code.  No value is being put in the text box.  `$('#secondaryNaicsCode' + i)`  there is no value for `i` now  correct?  so there for  it will not populate the right textbox - thoughts?

Comment: @TonyLombardi, I still use the `i` in my code, your way of using was actually wrong, since your selector only got the already checked inputs and make a array of that, then that index would not match the textboxes index.

Comment: indeed sorry I just checked that.  let me implement this and see where it takes me.

Answer (score -1):

I got the code to work.  Took some good advice.

here's the code:

```
// gets values of check box in Secondary NAICS list
$('#secondaryNaicsButton').click(function() {
  $('.naicsCodeCheckbox:checked').each(function(e) {
    val = []
    val[e] = $(this).val();
    $('#secondaryNaicsCode'+e).val(val[e]);   
  }); 
});
```

## demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpMJt/3/)